# Como salvar a pagina atual de um dataTable em uma variável?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-datatables, datatable

Gostaria de salvar na variável pagina o valor da pagina atual de uma tabela usando o plugin DataTable, pela documentação deles acredito que seja mais ou menos assim, mas não está funcionando.

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
var pagina = table.page();
```

Comment: Dá algum erro ? o que acontece ? o que apresenta `console.log(pagina);` ?

Comment: aparece undefined

Comment: E `console.log(table);` dá o quê? Existe algum elemento com o id `myTable` ? o Jquery foi incluido  ? o plugin de datatables também foi incluído?

Comment: console.log(table);    dá [object objetc], minha dataTable ta funcionando perfeitamente, gostaria somente de conseguir salvar o numero da pagina em uma variável php.

Comment: Para isso tem de utilizar ajax. Guardar numa variável só se for em variável de javascript.

Comment: eu estou tentando gravar em uma variável javascript, mas não ta rolando.

Comment: já experimentou fazer `var pagina = table.page.info().page+1;` ? [Exemplo da documentação de datatables](https://datatables.net/reference/api/page.info())

Answer (score -2):

Testa para ver se assim funciona! Ai depois, se der certo, é só adaptar a sua necessidade. Boa sorte!

No exemplo a baixo, ao clicar no botão que contém o número de uma página ele informará qual a página selecionada:

```
var tabela = $('#ID_DA_TABELA').DataTable();
tabela.on('draw', function () {
    var info = tabela.page.info();
    alert('Pg. atual: '+(info.page+1));; //Informa via alert qual a página
});
```

O exemplo tá de acordo o que a Datatable nos mostra em sua documentação [oficial](https://datatables.net/reference/api/page()), mas foi aperfeiçoada para melhor atender a sua necessidade.

> Fonte:
> https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/67279/how-to-show-current-page-number-in-different-place-in-a-webpage#Comment_188005

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).